# How to sort the default XML schema body parameters generated by the swagger using swashbuckle for a .net core webapi project

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle

[image]

It needs to in ascending order in swagger sample request body type for the data contract deserialiser to deserialise it?

What do I do to get that working?For example this is the sample XML schema generated by swagger.

```
<SaveJourney>
<ShipmentTag>test123</ShipmentTag>
<SavedByUserId>test123</SavedByUserId>
<ShipmentId>bf8195f9-caf5-460d-b7a6-d23d6c9e1904</ShipmentId>
<JourneyId>7</JourneyId>
</SaveJourney>
```

I need this to be sorted in alphabetical order so that the data contract deserialser to deserialise it.

Comment: Anyone feel free to correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't believe order matters to deserialize.

Comment: Nope, the order should not matter, I do not know any that requires alphabetical order...  Are you using a custom deserialser ?

Comment: I am using the default data contract deserialiser which wants the XML body to be ordered alphabetically to deserialise it.I need to modify the XML schema.

Comment: Can you create a sample project reproducing your issue and add it to GitHub?

Comment: I cannot provide a sample project but the sample XML request body which we get in the post and the put method in the swagger UI should be ordered alphabetically so that its deserialised correctly and the value is passed to the respective object...I just need to know the changes we need to make to the webapi or the swagger config file so that this is resolved.

Comment: I have also added an image to the prob statement...that request body is not ordered.

Comment: @shefalisingh please take a look at my answer below I think that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

using swagger 3, dotnet core 3.1
place in Startup.cs

```
public class SortModelDocumentFilter : Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
    {            
        var schemas = swaggerDoc.Components.Schemas.OrderBy(x=>x.Key).ToDictionary(x=>x.Key,y=>y.Value);
        swaggerDoc.Components.Schemas.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine($"{schemas?.Count}");
        foreach (var prop in schemas)
        {
            swaggerDoc.Components.Schemas.Add(prop.Key, prop.Value);
        }
        int k = 0;
        foreach (var schema in schemas)   Console.WriteLine($"{k++}. {schema.Key}");
                        
    }
}
```

and in ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) add

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(x => {
    ...
    x.DocumentFilter<SortModelDocumentFilter>();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The order you see in the sample is exactly what you have in your model.
If you want to change the order just change your model.

Here is an example:
http://swashbuckletest.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index?filter=Dict#/Dictionary/Dictionary_PostEcho

Here is the code behind that controller:
https://github.com/heldersepu/SwashbuckleTest/blob/master/Swagger_Test/Controllers/DictionaryController.cs#L25

If changing the model is not an option, you could create an **IDocumentFilter** to transform the final SwaggerDocument to suit your needs, here i have some samples:
https://github.com/heldersepu/SwashbuckleTest/blob/master/Swagger_Test/App_Start/SwaggerConfig.cs#L301

Comment: Hi,I used the Ischema filter to change the final schema but it did not work...I did not get the schema parameters ordered .                         public class SwaggerCustomXml : ISchemaFilter
    {
        public void Apply(Schema schema, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, Type type)
        {

            if (type.Name == "AnnouncementDto")
            {

                type.GetFields().OrderBy(e => e.Name);

            }
        }
    }

Comment: ...But you shouldn't have to do this with a any type of filters, instead order the code in your models to suit your needs